# Can someone with activated (in use) Sharingan be pulled into a genjutsu by another person with activated Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

I mean, I know Itachi was able to do it to Kakashi, but Kakashi only has (er, had) *one* Sharingan, not two. So, I guess my example would be if Itachi and Sasuke were fighting, both with their Sharingans blazing, could one pull the other into a Genjutsu just like they could do to anyone without Sharingan, or does both users having their Sharingan activated cancel it out? I can't find any information on this despite looking for a few hours!

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can do that.
The best example for it is probably the final [fight](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fated_Battle_Between_Brothers#Sasuke_vs._Itachi) between Sasuke and Itachi where the whole first part of it was just a genjutsu.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't even gotten nearly that far into the anime, I've pretty much given up trying to watch the whole thing haha